# Is there an Event in discord.py, that gets triggered by leaving a voice Channel? Sth like on_channel_leave?

Tags: discord.py

I want to delete a VoiceChannel after a User leaves it. Is there any kind of Event which is useful for this?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice_sta#discord.on_voice_state_update)

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    voice_channel = before.channel or voice.channel
   
    if before.channel is not None and after.channel is None:
        # delete the channel here
```

Comment: Its not getting triggered... Idk if i am to silly to copy paste or if there is an error in your code :D

Comment: You write `_update` in your first line, but `_delete` in your example. Perhaps that's the cause of confusion @Crxtxcal .

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Lukasz needs a tweak

```py
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    voice_channel = before.channel or voice.channel
   
    if before.channel and not after.channel: # before there was some channel but after member left that channel, after.channel is None
        await before.channel.delete()
```